# How do I add one point to my score every five seconds in vb.net when I click a button?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a game where you get points from clicking a button (one click = one point) then once you get to 100 points you can buy a manager, by clicking a different button called button2, where they add a point every five seconds but when you buy a manager for 100 points it turns to 800 points to buy  a manager so then you have two managers so thats 2 points every five seconds.

How do I add a point every five seconds? (Do I have to make a function?)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Score.Text >= 100 And Score.Text <= 800 Then
                If Button2.Text = "Buy One Manager for 100 Clicks" Then
                    Button2.Text = "Buy One Manager for 800 Clicks"
                    MsgBox("You have bought one manager")
                    Score.Text = Score.Text - 100
                    Managers.Text = Managers.Text + One
                    Clicks = (Clicks - 100) + (One * 4)
                End If
            ElseIf Score.Text >= 800 And Score.Text <= 6400 Then
                If Button2.Text = "Buy One Manager for 800 Clicks" Then
                    Button2.Text = "Buy Two Managers for 6400 Clicks"
                    MsgBox("You have bought one manager")
                    Score.Text = Score.Text - 800
                    Managers.Text = Managers.Text + One
                    Clicks = (Clicks - 800) + (One * 4)
                End If
            ElseIf Score.Text >= 6400 And Score.Text <= 51200 Then
                If Button2.Text = "Buy Two Managers for 6400 Clicks" Then
                    Button2.Text = "Buy Three Managers for 51200 Clicks"
                    MsgBox("You have bought two managers")
                    Score.Text = Score.Text - 6400
                    Managers.Text = Managers.Text + One
                    Clicks = (Clicks - 6400) + (One * 8)
                End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use timer with 5000 interval 
write your code here

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

End Sub
```